# Where to initialise my TableView DataController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I want to have a UITableViewController controlling my TableView.

Where (and how) should I call init on the UITableViewController?

---

**EDIT**
Here's my current code inside my `prepareForSegue` method:

```
    UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    ReccyTableViewController *tableViewController = (ReccyTableViewController *)[[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];

    ProjectDataController *aDataController = [[ProjectDataController alloc] init];

    [tableViewController setDataController:aDataController];

    [self presentViewController:tableViewController animated:YES completion:nil]; //Fails here
```

---

**EDIT #2**
Here's what I did in the end:

I scrapped trying to init the datacontroller in the prepareForSegue method and did it in the viewDidLoad method instead:

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad
  {
      [super viewDidLoad];
      _dataController = [[ProjectDataController alloc] init];
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[this](http://www.yetanotherchris.me/home/2010/10/18/uitableviewcontroller-by-example.html) may help you

read apple [official docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should call it from the point of your previous controller from where you want to add/push this tableViewController.

Comment: Okay, could you give me some sample code to play with please?